# Notepad++ How to replace every 11th character (25 characters per line) with a #

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace, replacement

I have a set of data - 25 characters long per line by a couple of hundred lines.

Each line / set of 25 characters per line consists of Numbers and Letters (both upper and lowercase)

I want to replace every 11th character (either number or letter) on each line with the character # so instead of

C8P6QagpFPJc4UMtkMAGxz9

I will have

C8P6QagpFP#c4UMtkMAGxz9

Can this be done in Notepad ++

Any assistance welcome.

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notepad++ Regex to replace the 4th character of each line in a text file.](https://superuser.com/questions/1032507/notepad-regex-to-replace-the-4th-character-of-each-line-in-a-text-file)

Comment: It's pretty simple, what have you tried? I suggest you to [learn some basics](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 1):

With ***Regular expression*** selected in the *Search Mode*, you can do:

Find what:

```
(^.{10}).(.*)
```

Replace with:

```
\1#\2
```

And press **Replace All**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find what : `^(.{10}).(.*)`
Replace with : `\1#\2`

If you only wish to handle 25-long lines (your data has 23), use :
`^(.{10}).(.{14})$`

[image]

Comment: Except for a better screenshot (ie it matches the text), this is literally the same answer as the first one.

Comment: To be fair I had it in the answer as well as `{0,10}` which isn't needed and can be `{10}`, but then edited it

Comment: @Berend: The answers were not identical when posted initially, and are different now. Both answers are now modified from their initial version.